# Get all roles in Nopcommerce 2.8

Tags: nopcommerce

I am trying to get all roles a user is assigned to in NOPCOMMERCE. I know how to find out if a user is in a specific role, but I can't get all roles in a list or in a listbox.

If I use the following code:

```
Imports Nop.Core.Infrastructure
Imports Nop.Services.Helpers
Imports Nop.Core.Domain.Customers
Imports Nop.Services.Customers
Imports Nop.Core

ListBox1.DataSource = EngineContext.Current.Resolve(Of IWorkContext)().CurrentCustomer.CustomerRoles()
ListBox1.DataBind()

'this is the listbox on aspx page
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
```

I get this in the listbox:

```
System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.CustomerRole_6E0DFC682B2D3247B3BEEED3063345A95D5742CE33B2761C4CB20A8C0A0AD639
System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.CustomerRole_6E0DFC682B2D3247B3BEEED3063345A95D5742CE33B2761C4CB20A8C0A0AD639
System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.CustomerRole_6E0DFC682B2D3247B3BEEED3063345A95D5742CE33B2761C4CB20A8C0A0AD639
System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.CustomerRole_6E0DFC682B2D3247B3BEEED3063345A95D5742CE33B2761C4CB20A8C0A0AD639
```

Which shows 4 roles, but they don't look like roles to me. I need the actual role name. Does anyone have an idea how I can get all roles a user has? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify in the listbox the DataTextField and DataValueField to tell listbox what fields of the CustomerRole is going to show.

```
ListBox1.DataSource = EngineContext.Current.Resolve(Of IWorkContext)().CurrentCustomer.CustomerRoles()

//add this
ListBox1.DataTextField  = "SystemName"; //you can use "Name" instead of "SystemName" or whatever property name of CustomerRole class
ListBox1.DataValueField = "Id";

ListBox1.DataBind()
```